# Role of Anti-Hermitian operators in Copenhagen interpretation of QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

One of the postulates of Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics is that every observable has a Hermitian operator **A**. With these operators we can then find eigenvalues of observables, make a time-evolution of a wave function and, in general, calculate the properties of the system.

However we also introduce anti-Hermitian operators.
*My question is:* What is the use for anti-Hermitian operators, if observables are described with Hermitian operators?

NOTE: I am just diving into the subject of Quantum mechanics, so I hope this question makes sense and is not "too basic".

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195149/

Comment: Notice that in complex quantum mechanics, any Hermitian operator $X$ can be turned into an anti-Hermitian one $iX$. The exponentiation of the latter gives a unitary transformation. An example of this is the exponentiation of $i H$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system, giving time evolution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The dual role of (anti-)Hermitian operators in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195149/)

Comment: I think the linked question answers mine, thank you. However, just to clarify, anti-Hermitian operators are used (in general) as generators for unitary transformations to preserve Hilbert space structure, as Hermitian operators represent observables in quantum mechanical space? (Speaking very generally)?